# Adding redux-thunk cause remote-redux-devtools not to work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-devtools

When I add redux-thunk to my react native project, my redux remote devtools does not hold any state. The state says undefined in the remote devtools window. Previously (devtools working):

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  devToolsEnhancer()
)
```

Change to (devtools stopped working):

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  devToolsEnhancer()
)
```

Am I doing the wrong order in `createStore`?

Update: I think `composeEnhancers` is needed. Tried a few variations of this but not working:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
  devToolsEnhancer()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [remote-redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools) github page:

Instead of

```
import devToolsEnhancer from 'remote-redux-devtools'
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  devToolsEnhancer()
)
```

do:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools'
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted, it works for me.